# Output of custom loss in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, cross-entropy

I know there are many questions treating custom loss functions in Keras but I've been unable to answer this even after 3 hours of googling.

Here is a very simplified example of my problem. I realize this example is pointless but I provide it for simplicity, I obviously need to implement something more complicated.

```py
from keras.backend import binary_crossentropy
from keras.backend import mean
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    zeros = tf.zeros_like(y_true)
    index_of_zeros = tf.where(tf.equal(zeros, y_true))
    ones = tf.ones_like(y_true)
    index_of_ones = tf.where(tf.equal(ones, y_true))

    zero = tf.gather(y_pred, index_of_zeros)
    one = tf.gather(y_pred, index_of_ones)

    loss_0 = binary_crossentropy(tf.zeros_like(zero), zero)
    loss_1 = binary_crossentropy(tf.ones_like(one), one)

    return mean(tf.concat([loss_0, loss_1], axis=0))
```

I do not understand why training the network with the above loss function on a two class dataset does not yield the same result as training with the built in `binary-crossentropy` loss function. 
Thank you!

**EDIT**: I edited the code snippet to include the mean as per comments below. I still get the same behavior however.

Comment: How is the result different? Complete different, or not?

Comment: Different accuracy, different predictions?

Comment: Yes, it goes from 83% acc. using the built-in function to 55% acc. using my function (same random seeds)

Comment: @mickey Both, different accuracy and predictions.

Comment: `tf.concat` just concatenates the two objects, you need to combine them somehow (maybe with `tf.mean`?) so you get the correct loss.

Comment: So the output of the loss function is a scalar? Or a tensor of the same shape as `y_true`?
I am confused because this [binary cross entropy loss]( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/binary_crossentropy)
uses this [funciton](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) which returns the same shape as the input.

Comment: @mickey I just tried `tf.reduce_mean`, which does not produce an error, but again the same 55% accuracy.

Comment: Try `metrics = ['binary_accuracy']` in the compile statement. My experience has been that using a custom loss function (especially for binary classification) that the accuracy function gets messed up, and changing `metrics` has proven useful.

Comment: @mickey I still get the same 55%. I would imagine if the predictions are different then there's something fundamentally wrong. I am plotting the decision boundary and it's totally messed up when I use the custom loss.

Comment: @zii Agreed, I suspect the calculation of the loss is just wrong. Perhaps you need to take the means of `loss_0` and `loss_1` separately and them add them together? Taking the straight mean of the two wouldn't account for any class imbalance, not matter how small.

Comment: @mickey I tried that too but it doesn't work. And yes the loss functions do not match but I really have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The `tf.where` function behaves very differently when the shape is "unknown".
To fix the snippet above simply insert the following lines right after the function is declared:

```py
y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])
```